# Adding multiple buttons in TinyMce in a loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a config list for buttons like this:

```
var config = [{
  name: 'first',
  insertionConfig: {
    title: 'first button',
    onsubmit: function(){
    // do sth
    }
  }
},{
  name: 'second',
  insertionConfig: {
    title: 'second button',
    onsubmit: function(){
    // do sth
    }
  }
}
 ]
```

and in my TinyMce plugin I want to add all buttons according to their config. So it would end up like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myPlugin', function(editor, url) {
      for (var i in config) {
        item = config[i];
        editor.addButton(item.name, {
          text: item.name,
          onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: item.insertionConfig.title,
                onsubmit: item.insertionConfig.onsubmit
              }
            };
          }
        });
```

but when I click on first button, it shows the second button's title. all configs of buttons refer to last added button. I know problem is something about the 'item' in the loop (all buttons refer to same item object which is the last one) but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a locally scoped variable for item inside the onclick function:

The issue you are running into is how variables are managed in JavaScript at the time the function is actually run.  The click function is not actually run until you click an item and at that time `item` is pointing to the last item in the array.

***EDIT***:  Check out this TinyMCE Fiddle for how this may happen: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/REfaab/1

Comment: @Micheal : I did that but it didn't solve the problem. 'thisItem' variable that you mentioned still refers to the same 'item' variable so it won't solve the problem.

Comment: @R.Abbasi see my edit and TinyMCE Fiddle link in my edited answer.

Comment: @Micheal, worked like a charm! So we must copy the item in the setting itself. Thank you very much for the tip